# UnitTest returns incorrect VMQWeight

Tags: c#, powershell

I created a powershell method in C# to change some things regarding VMNetworkAdapter.

```
 private void NetworkAdapterMod(VirtualMachine vm)
    {
        using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powerShell.AddScript(string.Format("Set-VMNetworkAdapter \"{0}\" -routerguard on -DhcpGuard on -VmqWeight 0", vm.ToVirtualMachineName()));

            powerShell.Invoke();

            if (powerShell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
            {
                throw powerShell.Streams.Error.First().Exception;
            }
        }
    }
```

This works just fine. I've tested it by creating a new VM and running the Get-VMNetworkAdapter cmd in powershell. All values return what I want them to.

I also created a UnitTest to test if it's running properly

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void Network_Adaptor_Secure_Test()
    {
        //Arrange
        var mgr = new VirtualMachineManager(new MockAppUser(), new VirtualMachineTask(new VirtualMachineDataService()), new MockAlertService());

        //Act 
        var virtualMachineID = CoreCreateVirtualMachine(mgr);

        //Assert
        var routerGuard = "";
        var dhcpGuard = "";
        var vmqWeight = 0;
        using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powerShell.AddScript("Get-VMNetworkAdapter \"(99) UnitTest\" | Select routerguard, DhcpGuard, VmqWeight");
            var ret = powerShell.Invoke();
            if (powerShell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
            {
                throw powerShell.Streams.Error.First().Exception;
            }
            foreach (var o in ret)
            {
                routerGuard = o.Properties["routerguard"].Value.ToString();
                dhcpGuard = o.Properties["DhcpGuard"].Value.ToString();
                vmqWeight = Convert.ToInt32(o.Properties["VmqWeight"].Value);
            }

            Assert.AreEqual("On", routerGuard);
            Assert.AreEqual("On", dhcpGuard);
            Assert.AreEqual(0, vmqWeight);
        }
    }
```

When I run this test, vmqWeight in my foreach loop says 100 when it should be 0. I double check in powershell to see what the VMQWeight is, and it's set to 0.

Why is it showing that vmqWeight is set to 100 in my UnitTest?Any help would be appreciated, thanks.